# How to display one CGridView from two databases

Tags: php, yii, multiple-databases, cgridview

i am trying to display two database tables source in one CGridView..
2 tables were reg.students and login.user..
my students model relation is,

```
public function relations()
{

     Yii::app()->getModule('user');
    return array(
        'royaltyOutstandings' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'RoyaltyOutstanding', 'studentID'),
        'srkMedicalInfos' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'SrkMedicalInfo', 'studentID'),
        'parents' => array(self::HAS_ONE, 'SrkParents', 'studentID'),
        'srkStudentWorksheets' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'SrkStudentWorksheet', 'studentID'),
        'user' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'User', 'centre_id'),
    );
}
```

In user module,

```
public function tableName()
{ return 'login.user'; }
```

in cgridview columns array,

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
'id'=>'students-grid',
'dataProvider'=>$model->search(),
'filter'=>$model,
'columns'=>array(
            array(
        'header' => 'No.',
        'value' => '$row+1',
    ),
     array('name' => 'user.centre_id',
    'value'=>'$data->user->centre_id',
    ), 
    '... // & so on
```

Controller action is,

```
    public function actionAdmin()
{   
    $this->layout = 'column3';
    $form = new Reports ;
    $model=new Students('search');
    $model->unsetAttributes();  // clear any default values
    if(isset($_GET['Students']))
        $model->attributes=$_GET['Students'];

    $this->render('admin',array(
        'model'=>$model,
        'form'=>$form,
    ));
}
```

Comment: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CArrayDataProvider - it can provide any data you want from any datasource you want

Comment: @RuslanPolutsygan, thnx for ur info.. letme check this link n comeback again

Comment: May i hav any sample codes for connection between two databases

Comment: you said you have already connected to both databases. Just retrieve info you need using either plain SQL or ActiveRecord, put it into array, wrap with CArrayDataProvider and supply it for `dataProvider` property in `CGridView`. Perhaps you need to exec several queries(since your data is splitted between several databases).

Comment: by plain sql, i can get the results from the table, im trying to display these both tables into single gridview.

Comment: i think, there may be any error in relations, maybe, not sure.. but if i use plain sql on the database, i can get the result

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you want to show one or more relations in your gridview.
If this is what you want, have a look at this tutorial: http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/281/searching-and-sorting-by-related-model-in-cgridview/
This tutorial doesn't only show you how to show a relation in your gridview but it also shows you how to sort and filter the data. good luck!

Comment: thnx alot for your reply, I tried these, upto my knowledge.. actually in my gridview trying to display the related datas from database1.table1 and database2.table2 where table2 is under modules-> model.. when i try to get the value of table2, which gives null. i dunno how to get the data from database2.table2

Comment: Ok, so you want to get the data from table 2 from a different database? If so, are you connecting to this second database because Yii does not do this natively to my knowledge.

Comment: @JelledeFries, Yes, i have connected with both databases, i did some funtions with both the database tables.